# Google Maps offline support

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am using GoogleMap fragment for adding maps in my application. As per our requirement we need to support offline maps. i.e if the device is offline(not connected to internet) and the cache of my app is cleared I am not able to see the tiles of maps.So I need to show the map even in this situation.

Can you please suggest the best approach for implementing this functionality? Is there any api's or sdk provided by google Maps for implementing this feature?

Please suggest the best possible way to do so.Also is it valid as per google map's terms and conditions?

Thanks

Comment: map has huge data. i think GoogleMaps onffline support is impossible.

Comment: Use ArcGis Map instead of Google Map...follow this......https://www.arcgis.com/features/maps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Google Maps for offline maps as google denies it in it's T&C. Instead you could use OpenStreetMaps (OSMDroid) which enables you to do that. The documentations can be found here.
 https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles

Some good tutorials

http://www.haakseth.com/?p=30

http://datamoil.blogspot.ae/2011/05/offline-google-maps-on-osmdroid.html